# change application resources in code

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have an application resource in App.xaml (see below) that i would like to be able change from MainPage.xaml.cs, is there anyway to do this? and if so how?

App.xaml:

```
<!--Application Resources-->
<Application.Resources>
    <System:Double x:Key="spinnerAngle">0</System:Double>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// retrieve
double spinnerAngle = (double)App.Current.Resources["spinnerAngle"]

// set
App.Current.Resources["spinnerAngle"] = spinnerAngle ;
```